# Default RadGrid html encoding

Tags: asp.net, security, webforms, telerik, html-encode

ASP.NET webforms application uses Telerik components (grid, labels, dropdowns) to display data.

Requirement is to `html encode` the data while rendering the data on UI. There is implemented whitelist to allow couple of secure html tags like `<table>`, `<b>`, `<br>`. Customized http encoder is configured in `web.config`.

- web.config

```
<httpRuntime encoderType="WebApp.Common.Security.AppHttpEncoder, WebApp.Common" />
```

Telerik grid allows to configure html encoding e.g. in c# but here the whitelisting is **NOT** required.

```
protected void RadItemsGrid_ColumnCreated(object sender, GridColumnCreatedEventArgs e)
{
    var boundColumn = e.Column as GridBoundColumn;
    if (boundColumn != null)
    {
        boundColumn.HtmlEncode = true;
    }
}
```

Quesion is how to set the .NET default html encoder to Telerik grid? Is there a way to set in code? Something like

```
RadGrid.Encoder = xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

There were done in the end these actions

- web.config - removed custom httpEncoder so everywhere is used just the default .NET one.
- Custom AppHttpEncoder is used explicitely where needed

This helped to improve performance, have html encoding everywhere by default and where needed the code got adjusted and custom whitelisting http encoder is used.